# Layer drop and update caffe model

Tags: python, c++, caffe

I need to update a caffe model from an existing caffe model where I will drop last two layers. It is needed to reduce caffe model size so that it would be easier and lesser size to deploy. Say my existing caffe model is **A1.caffemodel** which has ***5 convolution layers*** and ***3 fully connected layers***. I want to generate a new model from it named **B1.caffemodel** which will have ***5 convolution layers*** and ***1 fully connected layer*** (last 2 fc layers discarded).

I appreciate your all valuable suggestions and helpful code snippet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fully connected layers can indeed be very heavy. Please look at section "3.1 Truncated SVD for faster detection" at [*Girshick, R* **Fast-RCNN** ICCV 2015](https://arxiv.org/abs/1504.08083) describing how to use [SVD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition) trick to *significalntly* reduce the burden of fully connected layers. Hence, you can replace your three fully connected layers with 6 very thin layers.

Steps to go from model `A` to `B`:

1. Create `B.prototxt` that has the 5 convolution layers **with the same `"name"`s** as `A`.
2. Give the single fully connected layer in `B` a new `"name"` that does not exist in `A`.
3. in python

   ```
   import caffe
   B = caffe.Net('/path/to/B.prototxt', '/path/to/weights_A.caffemodel', caffe.TEST)
   B.save('/path/to/weights_B.caffemodel')
   ```
4. Now you have weights for `B` that are the same as the weights of `A` for all convolutional layers and **random** for the new single fully connected layer.
5. fine tune model `B` starting from `'/path/to/weights_B.caffemodel'` to learn the weights for the new single fully connected layer.

Comment: coming to think of it, you can skip steps 3 and 4 and fine-tune `B` from command line with `-weights /path/to/weights_A.caffemodel`: caffe will automatically take from weights_A the parameters for all convolutional layers (they have the same "name") and randomly init the new fully connected layer (since it cannot find its "name" in `weights_A`).

Answer (score 2):

C++ implementation:

```
    Net<float> caffe_net("B.prototxt", caffe::TEST);
    caffe_net.CopyTrainedLayersFrom("A.caffemodel");

    caffe::NetParameter net_param;
    caffe_net.ToProto(&net_param);
    caffe::WriteProtoToBinaryFile(net_param, "B.caffemodel");
```

Comment: C++ implementation of step 3 in [Shai's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40480678/1714410).