# Save caffe model after deleting layers from it

Tags: python, python-3.x, deep-learning, caffe

I have a caffe model with me which has `crop` layers in it so converting it to TensorFlow is posing a problem.
I have successfully loaded the model and dropped the `crop` layers and now I would like to save the corresponding `model.prototxt` and `model.caffemodel`
I found the following questions on StackOverflow but they are about replacing the layers and not permanently deleting them:
[Layer drop and update caffe model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40479864/layer-drop-and-update-caffe-model)
[How to modify the Imagenet Caffe Model?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41045335/how-to-modify-the-imagenet-caffe-model)

When I save the model using `caffe.Net.save()` only the `model.caffemodel` file gets saved and not the corresponding `.prototxt`. What to do ?
Model files : https://github.com/Charrin/RetinaFace-Cpp/tree/master/convert_models/mnet
Code used so far -

```
import caffe
net = caffe.Net('mnet.prototxt', 'mnet.caffemodel' , caffe.TEST)
del net.layer_dict['crop1']
del net.layer_dict['crop0']
net.save('new_model.caffemodel')
```